# Does lava include similar pattern of flowing just like water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing Minecraft for a while, and I noticed that lava behaves nearly the same as water. Are they behaved as the same properties? Or does lava respond differently from various changes in terrains?

Comment: The wiki pages for both water and lava are pretty long and give a lot of information. What exactly are you interested in?

Comment: As far as I can see, he is asking about behavior when flowing. Not where to find it, how deep it goes, how far it flows, just how much different two are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lava spreads slower and shorter distance (except in the Nether, where water can't be placed and lava flows faster and further), but otherwise spreads using the same rules as water blocks.

It also can not "create" source blocks unlike waterFor example:

WXW

W= Water source block
X= Empty block

Since two water source blocks adjacent to empty block, a new water source block is created.

However, this does not apply to lava blocks. New lava source blocks can not be created using this method.

Finally, when encountering water, lava turns into cobblestone unless the lava block that touches water is a source block, in this case it turns into obsidian.

Comment: “Lava spreads slower and shorter distance” ... except in the nether.

Comment: I am kinda assuming he refers to the overworld, but true. I will add mention of it.

Answer (score 0):

> Or does lava respond differently from various changes in terrains?

Nope. Lava behaves just like water.. Except in the overworld and end: it flows slower and lesser and is affected by the stream effect just like water.

*The "Stream Effect" is where water flows directly towards an edge within 7 (or whatever the flow limit for the liquid is minus one; 4-1=3 in the case of lava) blocks instead of spreading out like normal.